# How to disable listing .cab and .zip archives as folders, in explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, zip, cab

There's a couple suggestions, here, about this (and plenty others, elsewhere), but none of them really answers the question the way I'm looking for.

This comment: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13619-zip-folders-enable-disable-windows-explorer-view-5.html#post1445324) seems to address it as intended, for `.zip` files, but misses the `.cab` files.

Problem is attributes for cabs (`0x680001a0`), under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0CD7A5C0-9F37-11CE-AE65-08002B2E1262}\ShellFolder`, aren't the same as for zips, so how should I set those, in order to disable displaying them as folders, as well?

Note that I just want to disable having them listed as folders in explorer, not disable any other functionality (I'm using WinRAR, though, so they're associated with it, now).

**Edit:**

The linked article has a typo: the stated `Attributes` value is written within quotes and that results in a `string` attribute with a data value of `dword:680001a0` being written to registry, instead of the correct `dword` attribute with a data value of `680001a0`.
Line should be as follows: `"Attributes"=dword:000001a0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link shows .zip attributes being changed from 0x200001a0 to 0x000001a0, so it's clearing 0x20000000, which is [SFGAO_FOLDER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/sfgao) so your .cab attributes would be 0x480001a0.

Comment: Thanks. I have no cab files to verify it atm, but seems logic. Btw, you need RunAsTI or similar (which requires disabling Windows Defender Real Time Protection) to edit those entries, and to restart Windows Explorer to apply them.